# Scala selects wrong implicit conversion from within implicit class method

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicit-class

The compiler is failing to choose the correct implicit conversion method when that conversion occurs within an implicit class declaration. In the example below, I have a `Foo[T]` class and an implicit `Helper` class that takes a `Foo` and provides a `print` method. That print method calls `show`, which is itself a method provided by an implicit conversion on `Foo`.

The catch is that there are two possible conversions that provide `show`: one converts `Foo[T]` to a `Bar[T]` and the other converts `Foo[Array[T]]` to a `BarArray[T]`. The idea is that when we have a `Foo` that contains an array, we want to apply the more specific `BarArray` conversion. As far as I understand, the compiler chooses the conversion with the most specific type first.

This works in normal contexts as shown in the example below, but breaks within the context of the `print` method in the implicit `Helper` class. There, the same `show` method is called and therefore I would expect the same conversions should be applied. However, in this context the compiler always chooses the `Bar` conversion, even when it has a `Foo[Array[T]]` and should choose the `BarArray` conversion.

What is going wrong?

Minimal failing code example:

```scala
package scratch

import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Foo[T](val value: T) {}

object Foo {
  implicit def fooToBar[T](foo: Foo[T]): Bar[T] = {
    new Bar(foo.value)
  }

  implicit def fooArrayToBarArray[T](foo: Foo[Array[T]]): BarArray[T] = {
    new BarArray(foo.value)
  }
}

class Bar[T](val value: T) {
  def show(): String = {
    s"Bar($value)"
  }
}

class BarArray[T](val value: Array[T]) {
  def show(): String = {
    value.map(v => s"Bar($v)").mkString(", ")
  }
}

object Scratch extends App {

  implicit class Helper[T](foo: Foo[T]) {
    def print(): Unit = {
      println(foo.show())
    }
  }

  val foo0 = new Foo(123)
  val foo1 = new Foo(Array(123, 456))

  // conversions to Bar and BarArray work correctly here
  println(foo0.show())  // Bar(123)
  println(foo1.show())  // Bar(123), Bar(456)

  // conversions called from within the implicit Helper class
  // always choose the Bar conversion
  foo0.print  // Bar(123)
  foo1.print  // Bar([I@xxxxxxxx)  <- should be Bar(123), Bar(456)

}
```

Versions:

- Scala 2.12.10
- SBT 1.4.3
- JDK 1.8.0_241

Comment: You need a second helper for `Foo[Array[T]]` however I would recommend you to stop using so many implicit conversions and rather look for a **typeclass** based solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit resolution is "dispatched" in compile time so it only can access (type) information available to the compiler in particular place.

Here

```
  val foo0 = new Foo(123)
  val foo1 = new Foo(Array(123, 456))

  // conversions to Bar and BarArray work correctly here
  println(foo0.show())  // Bar(123)
  println(foo1.show())  // Bar(123), Bar(456)
```

compiler infers types and implicits this way:

```
  val foo0: Foo[Int] = new Foo(123)
  val foo1: Foo[Array[Int]] = new Foo(Array(123, 456))

  println(fooToBar(foo0).show())  // Bar(123)
  // fooArrayToBarArray instead fooToBar because
  // compiler knows that foo1: Foo[Array[Int]]
  println(fooArrayToBarArray(foo1).show())  // Bar(123), Bar(456)
```

However here:

```
  implicit class Helper[T](foo: Foo[T]) {
    def print(): Unit = {
      println(foo.show())
    }
  }
```

all compiler know is that foo: `Foo[T]`. The same code has to be resolved **now**, there are no implicits incoming as arguments and the solution would have to be compiled once, and then type erasure kick in leaving hardcoded value of whatever implicit was best suited here. `fooToBar` works perfectly. `fooArrayToBarArray` expects proof that Foo's parameter is `Array[T]` for some `T`, which is nowhere to be found. By passing array here, you are forgetting about it, stripping compiler from any possibility to use array-specific implementation.

That is why @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested type classes:

```
// type class
trait FooPrinter[A] {

  def show[A](foo: Foo[A]): String

  def print[A](foo: Foo[A]): Unit = println(show(foo))
}
object FooPrinter {

  // convenient summon method
  def apply[A](implicit printer: FooPrinter[A]): FooPrinter[A] = printer
}

class Foo[T](val value: T)
// making sure that arrayPrinter takes precedence over tPrinter
// if both match requirements
object Foo extends FooLowPriorityImplicits {

  implicit def arrayPrinter[T]: FooPrinter[Array[T]] =
    _.map(v => s"Bar($v)").mkString(", ")
}
trait FooLowPriorityImplicits {

  implicit def tPrinter[T]: FooPrinter[T] = v => s"Bar($v)"
}
```

```
implicit class Helper[T](private val foo: Foo[T]) extends AnyVal {

  // requiring type class and summoning it using summon method
  def print(implicit fp: FooPrinter[T]): Unit = FooPrinter[T].print(foo)
}

val foo0 = new Foo(123)
val foo1 = new Foo(Array(123, 456))

foo0.print
foo1.print
```

This way `Helper` will not have to pick one implicit and "hardcode" it, because it will be passed to at as an argument:

```
new Helper(foo0).print(tPrinter)
new Helper(foo1).print(arrayPrinter)
```

though conveniently for us it will be done by the compiler. In your example no such communication between outside of `Helper` and its inside happens, so whatever is resolved there is applied to everything that is passed.

Comment: Fixed, I am aware of the limitations but at 2AM I think slower.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me now. I will say that trying to reason my way around passing the implicit conversion as an implicit argument to a method in an implicit class took a few tries to understand. I think the way we re-use the word and key-word implicit in these different ways can cause confusion.

Comment: Everyone agrees. Which is why in Scala 3 `implicit` still works but is deprecated in favor of separate constructs for type classes (`given`, `using` keywords), extension methods (`extension` keyword) and conversions (extends `scala.Conversion`).